Prove that if a frame is dense then $\Box \Box A \to \Box A $ is valid
I am having trouble with the following question on modal logic.
A modal logic frame $M =\langle W, R\rangle$ is dense whenever
$$\forall x\forall y(Rxy\rightarrow\exists z(Rxz \land Rzy))$$
Prove that the formula $$\Box\Box A\to\Box A $$ is valid in every dense frame.
We don't make any assumptions about the frames. How can this be done?

My question is rather the opposite of this implication. I am assuming the frame is dense and want to show the implication must hold

You don’t need to assume the relation is transitive. Once you assume the frame is dense, and you assume that box box A is true at some world x (with arbitrary valuation function), then consider any world that x sees

this question shouldn't be marked as a duplicate, because the other question was about proving the opposite direction of this implication

Let $F=\langle W,R\rangle$ be a dense frame. Take some arbitrary valuation function $V$, and some arbitrary world $w \in W$. Suppose $\langle F,V\rangle, w \vDash \square\square A$. Take any $u$ s.t. $Rwu$. Then there exists some $z$ s.t. $Rwz$ and $Rzu$. So $\langle F,V\rangle, z \vDash \square A$, and $\langle F,V\rangle, u \vDash A$. Since $u$ was arbitrary, $\langle F,V\rangle, w \vDash \square A$.
